# Nginx not serving static files for django App

Tags: django, python-3.x, nginx, gunicorn

I am trying to deploy a Django project using nginx + gunicorn + mysql. All the configuration is done, but now my nginx is throwing 404 on any static content.

`setting.py`:

```py
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

Nginx conf file:

```
upstream app_server {
    server unix:/var/www/production/JDApps/jd/jd_gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name 10.1.1.2;

    keepalive_timeout 5;
    client_max_body_size 4G;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/jd-inventory-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/jd-inventory-error.log;

    location /static/ {
        alias /var/www/production/JDApps/jd/staticfiles;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /opt/;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }

    location @proxy_to_app {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }
}
```

Gunicorn startup script:

```py
#!/bin/bash

NAME="jd_inventory"
DJANGODIR=/var/www/production/JDApps/jd
USER=nginx
GROUP=nginx
WORKERS=3
BIND=unix:/var/www/production/JDApps/jd/jd_gunicorn.sock
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=jd.settings
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=jd.wsgi
LOGLEVEL=error
LOGFILE=/tmp/jd.log
echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

# Activate the virtual environment

cd $DJANGODIR
source ../venv/bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

# Start your Django Unicorn

exec ../venv/bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $WORKERS \
  --user=$USER \
  --group=$GROUP \
  --bind=$BIND \
  --log-level=$LOGLEVEL \
  --log-file=$LOGFILE
```

File Structure:

```py
[root@vm-1 JDApps]# pwd
/var/www/production/JDApps
[root@vm-1 JDApps]# ll
total 4
drwxr-xr-x. 7 nginx nginx 148 Aug 23 19:21 jd
-rw-r--r--. 1 nginx nginx 455 Aug 22 19:19 requirements.txt
drwxr-xr-x. 6 nginx nginx  69 Aug 22 19:19 venv
[root@vm-1 JDApps]# ll *
-rw-r--r--. 1 nginx nginx 455 Aug 22 19:19 requirements.txt

jd:
total 4
-rw-r--r--. 1 nginx nginx   0 Aug 22 22:30 filename_new.log
drwxr-xr-x. 4 nginx nginx 217 Aug 21 18:06 inventory
drwxr-xr-x. 3 nginx nginx  93 Aug 23 20:55 jd
srwxrwxrwx. 1 nginx nginx   0 Aug 23 19:21 jd_gunicorn.sock
-rw-rw-r--. 1 nginx nginx 622 Aug 21 18:06 manage.py
drwxrwxr-x. 4 nginx nginx  64 Aug 21 18:06 static
drwxr-xr-x. 6 nginx nginx  99 Aug 22 21:36 staticfiles
drwxrwxr-x. 3 nginx nginx 277 Aug 21 18:06 templates

venv:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x. 3 nginx nginx 4096 Aug 22 21:45 bin
drwxr-xr-x. 2 nginx nginx   24 Aug 22 19:17 include
drwxr-xr-x. 3 nginx nginx   23 Aug 22 19:17 lib
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 nginx nginx    3 Aug 22 19:17 lib64 -> lib
drwxr-xr-x. 3 nginx nginx   17 Aug 22 19:19 share
[root@vm-1 JDApps]#
```

With the above configuration nginx is throwing 404 at any static file:

```
10.1.1.1 - - [23/Aug/2019:19:22:09 -0400] "GET /static/admin/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "http://10.1.1.2:8000/admin/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36"

10.1.1.1 - - [23/Aug/2019:21:05:01 -0400] "GET /static/js/inventory.js HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "http://10.1.1.2/inventory/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36"
```

I don't understand why this is happening. I have static file in the folder "static" as well as "staticfiles". But nginx is not able to get any of this files.

**Update:**

I made this to work by changing nginx conf file to:

```
root /var/www/production/JDApps/jd;
```

And then copied django staic files from staticfiles to static folder.

So I guess the alias with the location block is not working as expected. Does anyone have a guess?

Comment: Try: `alias /var/www/production/JDApps/jd/staticfiles/;` with a trailing `/`.

Comment: Yes, now its working. Cant believe the issue was so simple. Thankx

Comment: Thanks a lot.  @RichardSmith Now working for me.

Comment: @RichardSmith You should move this to as answer, so others can find it easily.

Comment: with a trailing / not working for me.

Comment: please don't add [solved] or similar to the question title. You can mark an answer as accepted or add your own answer. Also don't edit the solution into the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
alias /var/www/production/JDApps/jd/staticfiles/;
```

with a trailing `/`.

Thanks to @Richard Smith's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57634394/solvednginx-not-serving-static-files-for-django-app#comment101724331_57634394).